# Xampp Database Replication Setup Error

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

**Scenario**

I've been trying to set up mysql database replication on my xampp server but its not been working. I get the following error

[image]

and the error logs display the following message.

```
2017-12-28 10:14:37 10384 [ERROR] Slave I/O: Fatal error: The slave I/O thread stops because master and slave have equal MySQL server ids; these ids must be different for replication to work (or the --replicate-same-server-id option must be used on slave but this does not always make sense; please check the manual before using it). Internal MariaDB error code: 1593
2017-12-28 10:14:37 10384 [Note] Slave I/O thread exiting, read up to log 'FIRST', position 4
```

I understand what the error is saying but im not sure how to fix it, i've look online and around at various solutions and followed some of what theyve said. (Couldn't follow all some people are using linux or mysql in the command line so i couldnt follow but i tried an alternative).

I've been following this error since im trying to set this all up on xampp:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nfsmnx24gxU

But its pretty outdated. Since i'm using xampp on windows there doesn't seem to be much up-to-date tutorials for this, they all show how to do it through linux terminal but obviously to me this isnt useful.

I'm also not sure how two separate servers are running on xampp in this scenario. Even if i visit "127.0.0.123" and "127.0.0.222" at the top of PhpMyAdmin it still shows that the current database is hosted on "127.0.0.1" so in this sense the replication process is slightly confusing me. Whats even more confusing is that it works flawlessly in the tutorial that i linked earlier.

I'm using the most up-to-date version of xampp, 28-12-2017.

**Question**

Does anyone know, on the current version of xampp, how to get past this error OR know of a tutorial that would help me set up replication on xampp on a windows computer.